# ModuleNotFoundError for PyTorch after Installation in Conda Environment

Tags: python

[img link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frJHt.png)
I've encountered an issue with importing PyTorch in a newly created conda virtual environment. Here's what I did:

1. I created a new virtual environment using conda and activated it.
2. I installed PyTorch within this environment using the appropriate conda command.
3. After the installation, I opened a Python interactive shell by simply typing python in the terminal.
   However, when I attempt to import PyTorch with import torch, I receive the following error:
   `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named'torch'`
   The strange part is that running pip freeze | grep torch confirms that torch==1.4.0 is indeed installed in the environment. I'm puzzled as to why Python can't find the module when it seems to be installed correctly. Could there be an issue with my environment path, or is there something else I'm overlooking?

When I realized that I can not import torch module in my Python interactive shell, I create a python script `demo.py` and run it:

```
import torch
```

But unfortunately, it didn't work.

Comment: instead of using python interactive shell try using anaconda prompt (it should come pre-installed with anaconda). 
Activate your anaconda environment, you can check all available envs like so: 
'conda env list'
from that list select you will see all available environments which you can run and then run the one you want like so:
'conda activate Your_Env'
once in, run your python by typing in 'python' and now you can run something like 'import torch' and if it isn't there try 'pip install torch' which should install into the active conda environment.
This is a know windows issue.